# To show Data in modal Pop up after click on Web Grid Column

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal, webgrid

My Data in Exception Column is very large and i decided to display the Action Link instead of Data and when User will click on that Link, modal Pop up will display the Data.I am able to show Model Pop up on the click of Action Link but my problem is that i am not able to show the Data corresponding to that Record in Modal Pop Up.
Below is my Javascript code for calling Modal PopUp

```
@model IList<ClaimBuildMVC.Models.ApplicationLog>
@{        
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SuperAdminLayout.cshtml";
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, canSort: false, canPage: false, columnNames: new[] { "Logger", "User", "Date", "Message", "Exception", "ErrorID" });
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ErrorLog').DataTable({
            "bSort": false,                
            "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page",
                "sSearch": ""
            }
        });
        $('.dataTables_filter input').attr("placeholder", "Search by Error details...");
        $(".ActionEdit").click(function () {
            $(".ActionEdit").removeAttr('href');
            $(".ExceptionModal").modal();
        });
    });
</script>
```

And below is Web Grid to display Data

```
<div class="Content-inner-pages">
    <div class="TopHeading TopHeading2">
        <h2>Error Log</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-content">
            <div class="CustomerUsers">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-content Custom-DataTable">
                        @grid.GetHtml(
                         htmlAttributes: new { id = "ErrorLog" },
                         fillEmptyRows: false,
                         alternatingRowStyle: "alternate-row",
                         tableStyle: "table table-hover dt-responsive CustomDatable",
                         headerStyle: "grid-header",
                         footerStyle: "grid-footer",
                         mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, columns: new[] {
                         grid.Column("Logger",header: "Page", canSort:false),
                         grid.Column("User",header:"UserId",canSort:false),
                         grid.Column("Date",header: "CreatedDate",canSort:false),
                         grid.Column("Message",header: "ErrorMessage",canSort:false),
                         grid.Column(header: "Exception", format:(item) =>
                             new HtmlString(Html.ActionLink("Edit", "#", new { id =item.ErrorID }, new { @class = "ActionEdit"}).ToString()
                         ))
                         })
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal fade ExceptionModal" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                //Here i want to Load Exception Column Data that will Display to End user
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Let me know where i am doing wrong or what should be the possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two steps for this
first store your current clicked td in a session or global variable like

```
$(".ActionEdit").click(function () {
        $(".ActionEdit").removeAttr('href');
        //storing your td in session 
        session["currentTdData"] = $(this);
        $(".ExceptionModal").modal();
    });
```

and then you have to fill your modal with your current td data on the bootstrap event of after loading modal popup

```
$('.ExceptionModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      // here you can session["currentTdData"] data 
})
```

Comment: not working mate..after adding your code modal pop up is not coming